# startsWith() returning unexpected values

Tags: java, data-structures, string, startswith

The class project has us reading in the title, artist and lyrics of 10,514 songs contained in a single text file.  The current section of the project had us write an ordered unrolled linked list and run a search on the title field.  The comparator was also written to sort the list by title.  We have to keep track of the comparisons required to find the matches

When testing, I'm getting some odd results.  For example, running a search for
**angel** returns 23 matches and requires 552 comparisons, which matches the answer given by the professor
**t** returns zero matches and requires 9530 comparisons, where 1148 matches were expected
**ta** returns 62 matches and requires 8455 comparisons
**s** returns no matches and 8383 comparisons were required
**sa** returns 89 matches and required 7355 comparisons

My search algorithm runs like this:

1. loop through the list to find the first match

   loop through the list to find the first instance that does not match the search field

   send the start and end objects to the Sublist method of the data structure, which loops through those two objects and builds a separate list of matches

   return list of matches

For both step one and two, I compare the current value to the search value via
 `if (currentSong.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(titleSearch))`

What is it about this line of code that returns false with a single letter search, but when an a is added, values are found?  Preferably, I'd like a solution that wouldn't require me to manually step through 8000-odd iterations of a loop in a debugger.  In addition, the professor provided tests to the structure with the expected values, and my code passed all the tests.

Comment: Can you post the expected matches and comparisons for t, ta, s, and sa? (By the way, your algorithm looks right.)

Comment: the only test matches provided were for 'angel' and 't'.  The other three tests are on my own with the same code.  what would make the addition of a single letter to a search make it return results?

Comment: I see. Can you post how you structured your for-loop for iterating through the list?

Comment: Hey bud - can you link us to your corpus (list of songs) ?

Comment: Have you tried without `startsWith()`? As in, `if(currentSong.getTitle().toLowerCase().length() >= titleSearch.length() && currentSong.getTitle().toLowerCase().substring(0, titleSearch.length()).equals(titleSearch))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.  In the subList method, I used a binary search method to identify the index location of the first found match.  However, since binary search returns only the first match it comes across, I had a loop to walk backwards thru the array to find the real first match.

However, in this case, the first hit returned from binary search was at the 0 index, so when I walked backwards, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException was thrown, thus short-circuiting the entire thing. Adding a second test solved the problem.